# Soft body cloth meshes being affected differently to each other

Tags: modifiers, constraints, soft-body, cloth-simulation

I have created four objects using soft bodies to simulate cloth which are being affected by force fields (wind) but two are behaving abnormally and I do not know why.

I have posted images (click for more) [image: http://imgur.com/a/wsYv] which show the result of animation and also the settings I have used. I am using constraints to hold the soft body cloth to another mesh, and the soft body cloth also has a wave modifier on it as well.

During the animation process two of the soft body meshes (sail) comes away from the mast. while the other two do not. You can see all of this in the images that I have posted.

Comment: It looks like the origin for them is off. Press Shift-Ctrl-Alt-C and and select "Origin to Geometry". Try this for both the sails and the constraint meshes/empties.

Comment: @CharlesL I followed your suggestion and although it has helped, they do not move as far away as they did before, they are still to far away from the mast. All of the problems seem to be at the start when the sails start moving, they are moving too fast, when the animation is up and running at full speed everthing is fine. Hope this helps

Comment: Does slowing down the simulation help?

Comment: @CharlesL could you explain to me what you mean as I am only animating it by presing Alt-A. The sails are moving as a direct result of the wind force field I have set up, with all gravity effects turned off.Cheers

Comment: I mean, what happens when you lower the wind force?

Comment: @CharlesL It is much better as the animation gets up to speed the sail is not as far away, but is still too far away compared to the other two sails.

Comment: Is there a difference in the settings between the front sails and the back sails, or the front constraints and the back constraints?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9495/discussion-between-lindsey-and-charlesl)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use softbody simulation rather than cloth sim? just wondering.

Comment: @gandalf3 I do not know the difference between softbody and cloth sim, i was just wondering if it was possible to make a boat move just from the animation of the sails themselves, and during the process of messing around with the modifiers I found it easier to accomplish this with the softbody meshes. if you wish to know anymore please contact me.

Comment: @Lindsey see this post for the difference between soft-body and cloth sim: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/what-is-the-technical-difference-between-softbody-and-cloth-simulation BTW, If you don't mind, I would be interested to see how you got the boat to move with just soft-body ;) (the images are kinda low res..)

Comment: @gandalf3 when i finish the textures and materials off i will upload file. Problem is though at the minute it is close to 50 mb and paste all will only take 30. so i am looking around for another dropbox app to use and then i will let you know. :-)

Comment: Did we ever get an answer for this one?