# How to make an object go through a plane but the plane deform with the face of the object?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, properties, soft-body

I wonder know how to make an **object go through a plane, but the plane deform with the face of the object**, as in the following Terminator video, in second 15 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovq9xOQNamk

I am really interested in this effect, I would appreciate if you can help me guys, thanks you[image: Deform Effect]

Comment: What have you already tried? What particular part of it are you stuck with?

Comment: I tried with Dynamic Paint first, monkey as brush, with waves as factor -1 type depth change, it makes a hole but it's a uncrontrollable circle hole wave, didn't work. Later I tried using Soft Body as monkey and plane as collision, didn't work, also I tried with cloth but I gave up, I don't know how to do this, I am pretty beginner to Physics modifiers...

Do you have any basic idea to get the object through a plane keeping the silhouette?

Thank you

Comment: It should just be a matter of heavily subdividing a plane and adding Cloth physics to it. Animate a mesh coming up underneath with collision modifier. Then tweak the cloth settings to stiffen it up a bit.

Comment: You are a genius, thanks a lot!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78769/how-to-create-vacuum-packaging https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7194/how-to-stretch-a-mesh-object-over-another/7195

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is with Cloth physics.

Start by animating your object raising up through a flat plane (keyframe it starting below the surface and then 'rise up' until it protrudes). Add physics Collision to both the plane and your object.

Create another plane and position this above the first. Heavily subdivide it so that the cloth can suitably drape over your object and add Cloth physics to it.

Run the animation and you should have something like the following :

[image: face pushing up]

(note that I artifically reversed the same frames to go back to the start of the animation - that isn't possible with the cloth physics!!)

You might want to tweak the cloth physics paramters to get the effect you're looking for.

Comment: what parameters did you use to archieve this? this is amazing, thank you a lot!

Comment: Glad to help. I mostly just changed the resistance to bending and increased the vertex mass. It isn’t an exact science since the cloth physics is only loosely based on real-world physics so a lot depends on your geometry and vertex density. Try changing the cloth presets - cotton would behave different to leather. A similar option is to use Soft Body physics instead of cloth, which gives you different parameters to adjust. This should let you create something that doesn’t tend to crease in the same way as cloth might - to get the loom you’re looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is by animating a displacement map. Here I just animated the scale value of the displacement. It doesn't have the smooth dropoff like you get with the cloth method, but you may find it useful. (don't ask why I used such a wonky shape, XD) [image]

[image]
[image]