# How to have part of a model stretch (have cloth simulation) when another model is inside it?

Tags: cloth-simulation

This is a very random question (I know it's weird) but I want to try edit a model's belly so that if I put another model inside it, the inside model leaves an impression on the outside.
I'm not really familiar with cloth simulations so I'm not sure if this is just something that could be done with that.

I'm sorry if this is weird but I really do appreciate any help.

(The reason it's bloated in the picture is because I used the inflate and bloat tools, the inside model didn't cause it, if anyone was wondering).

[image: This is the model I want to edit.]

Comment: Something like this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214091/how-to-make-an-object-go-through-a-plane-but-the-plane-deform-with-the-face-of-t/214309#214309

Comment: @Blunder Something like that would be helpful. I'm just not sure if I could apply something like that to part of a model (I'm very new to blender).

Comment: In the cloth settings, there is a *Shrink* factor. You could make the bloated belly shrink.