# How would I simulate a jellyfish on the ground?

Tags: physics

I want to simulate a squishy body like that of an jellyfish. The goal is to have one frame where it is at rest on the ground to render an image. The point of the simulation is to have it fold believably.

I have tried with cloth simulation but it didn't work at all. It didn't keep the shape and just swelled out like a balloon.

I have tried soft body simulation but I also want the body to fold and not look so much like a rubber objectl

Is it a matter of tweaking the settings?

Comment: Yes it is only a matter of tweaking the settings. Go with softbody though. Fiddle with the edge spring values and bending under Soft Body Edges, also enable Stiff Quads.

Comment: This may be off topic because this question is too localized in its current form and is unlikely to be applicable outside of a very narrow context. Consider broadening the scope of this question in order to make it more useful for future users of the site.

Comment: Depending on how you want it to "squish", you might want to try using cloth simulation instead of soft body simulation. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1425/599